# Unable to install Nodemon

Tags: ubuntu-mate, nodejs

I am currently running Ubuntu-MATE 16.04 and whenever I try and install Nodemon so I can work on a Node.js site I get this:

> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.2

and it doesnt seem to install, I am running this command to install:

> npm install nodemon --save

Comment: first adress architecture, are you running 64-bit or 32-bit? and which is the package?

Comment: @ravery Its 64-bit and I am running Nodejs v4.2.6 and npm v3.5.2

Comment: is the package also 64-bit?

Comment: @ravery I dont know, how would i be able to find that out?

Comment: are you installing from a third party source? debian based distros usually appends the suffix :i386 to 32-bit packages

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please [edit] the output of `dpkg -l npm` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so I solved the issue, it turns out that the file was actually installing. Although it wasn't becoming accessible from the command-line.

So adding:

```
"serve": "nodemon server.js"
```

in the scripts section of **package.json** for your node.js project, then you want to run this command to start it:

> npm run serve

just make sure that you are in the project directory